# appendChild new paragraph on form submit not working

Tags: javascript, dom, form-submit

I'm trying to add a paragraph to my dom/html/site(I'm new to html and js) through javascript when a form is submitted. This is what I have so far:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function()
{
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", add, false);
});

function add(e)
{
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var newText = document.createTextNode("new text");
    para.appendChild(newText);

    document.documentElement.lastChild.appendChild(para);
}
```

The paragraph seems to get added, I can see "new text" for a split second when I click on the submit button but then it immediately disappears.

Comment: The submit button is submitting the form, causing a reload of the page. Have the *add* function do `e.preventDefault()` and return false.

Comment: because the page is submitted!

Comment: @RobG I changed it, it's still disappearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple points here,

1. Your submit button is causing the page to reload, meaning your page is effectively reset to it's *just loaded* state, call `e.preventDefault()` to stop this from happening.
2. A `<p>` element should not be a descendant of a non-`<body>` tag, and you can't always guarantee that the `.lastChild` of a `<html>` will be a `<body>`. It's better to use `document.body` for this.

Comment: thank you, this fixed it. I'll accept in 5 minutes when I can:)

Comment: Though the body will always be the [*lastElementChild*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-lastelementchild) in an HTML document. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I am torn that those properties exist, on the one hand they're really useful because you usually want elements, on the other hand I don't like pretending that there aren't any other types of _Node_... also you missed the word **valid** ;)

Comment: @PaulS.—browsers will create a valid HTML document object regardless of whether the markup is valid (not so for XML of course). ;-) The quirks are getting fewer…

Comment: @RobG `document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
document.documentElement.lastElementChild; // <p>`

Comment: It should throw a [*DOMException*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) since "… *this node is of a type that does not allow children of the type of the `newChild node`*" but there you go. :-( But anyway, what I was referring to is that if a P is placed after the closing *body* tag in the markup, it will be moved to inside the body.